# Kinvey Javascript Method Not Working in iPad but works in simulator

Tags: ipad, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an iPad application with PhoneGap and jQueryMobile and Kinvey's Javascript method for data storage. It's working fine in simulator and I am not able to get it working in the iPad. I am attaching the index.html code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,width=device-width, user-scalable=no;" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.theme-1.1.0.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="datetime/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="datetime/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.js"/>
<script async src="kinvey-js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
     if(typeof Kinvey != 'undefined')
     {
          alert('Kinvey is there');
     }
     else
     {
          alert('Kinvey is not there');
     }
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   Test
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the alert message "Kinvey is there", when I run on simulator and I am getting the alert message "Kinvey is not there" on my iPad.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried loading the library non-async?, change

```
<script async src="kinvey-js.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="kinvey-js.js"></script>
```

Since you're not pulling the library from our AWS bucket you don't need to load the library async.  See if this helps make the loading more predictable.

Comment: Tested that. It works only in non-async mode. Kinvey won't work with datebox(datepicker). Changed the datepicker. Now its working fine.      Thanks For your help....